# How to get a table result in my Shiny App without the reference column?

Tags: r, shiny

When I get the tableOutput() in the App it comes with the referece column.. Here follows the image of my output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wt2h.png

How do I get rid of this?

Here follows this section of my code:

```
   #server

    dados3 <- eventReactive (input$estado, {subset(States_Cities_Premiums, States_Cities_Premiums[,1] %in% input$estado)})

    output$dados3 <- renderTable({

    subset(dados3(), dados3()[,2] %in% input$lista)[,c(2,3)]

   })

   #ui

     br(),
     tableOutput("dados3"),
     br(),
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Try to remove names from the table with:  `rownames(df) <- NULL`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
#server

    dados3

 <- eventReactive (input$estado, {subset(States_Cities_Premiums, States_Cities_Premiums[,1] %in% input$estado)})

    output$dados3 <- renderTable({

    subset(dados3(), dados3()[,2] %in% input$lista)[,c(2,3)]

   }, include.rownames=FALSE)

   #ui

     br(),
     tableOutput("dados3"),
     br(),
```